# On the degree elevation needed to bring Bernstein coefficients to [0, 1]

Tags: polynomials

Take a polynomial $f(x)$ of even degree $n$ of the form—$${n \choose {n/2}}x^{n/2}(1-x)^{n/2} k,$$where $k>1$ is the $(n/2)$th Bernstein coefficient of the polynomial.  (With these properties, $f$ peaks at the point 1/2 in the interval [0, 1] and is nonnegative everywhere in [0, 1].)

Suppose $f(1/2) \in (0, 1)$, and suppose the polynomial's degree is elevated enough times that all its Bernstein coefficients are in the interval $[0,1]$.  Let $r$ be the smallest number of degree elevations needed before this happens.

<s>Then experiments show that $r/n$ appears to have a limit of $1/3$ as $n$ approaches infinity.</s>

I further conjecture that it is enough to elevate $f(x)$, floor($n/3$)+1 times to bring all its Bernstein coefficients to the interval $[0, 1]$.

My question is:  Is there a proof of these claims?  It is nothing I could find so far in the papers on Bernstein polynomials.

---

EDIT:

An answer provided a useful lower bound on the number of degree elevations, namely $r \ge \frac{nf(1/2)^2}{1-f(1/2)^2} = m$.  My new question is:  Is it enough to elevate $f(x)$, floor($m$)+1 times to bring all its Bernstein coefficients to the interval $[0, 1]$?

Comment: By elevating the degree $r$ times, do you mean expressing it in terms of the degree $n+r$ Bernstein basis polynomials, and you want to find the minimum $r$ such that the coefficients of the degree $n+r$ basis polynomials are nonnegative and at most $1$?

Comment: @WillSawin: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$ f(x) = {n \choose {n/2}}x^{n/2}(1-x)^{n/2} k = 2^n f(1/2) x^{n/2}(1-x)^{n/2} = 2^n f(1/2) x^{n/2} (1-x)^{n/2} ( x+ (1-x))^r = \sum_{j=0}^r 2^n f(1/2)  \binom{r}{j}  x^{n/2+j}(1-x)^{n/2 + r-j} $$

so the $n/2+j$th [Bernstein coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial) is $$ \frac{  2^n f(1/2)  \binom{r}{j}  } { \binom{n +r }{ n/2 + j } } .$$

These are certainly nonnegative, so it suffices to check when these are at most $1$. Increasing $j$ by one multiplies this expression by $\frac{r-j}{j+1} \frac{ n/2 +j+1}{ n/2 +r-j} = \frac{ (r-j)(j+1) + (r-j)(n/2) }{ (r-j)(j+1) + (j+1) (n/2)}$ which increases when $j+1< r-j$ and decreases when $j+1< r-j$, so the maximum is attained at $j=r/2$ (or $\frac{r \pm 1}{2}$ if $r$ is odd.)

Thus ($r$ even, for simpilicity), it suffices to know when the inequality
$$ 2^n \binom{r}{r/2} f(1/2) \leq \binom {n+r}{(n+r)/2}$$ holds.

Since $\binom{r}{r/2} \approx 2^r \sqrt{\frac{2}{ \pi r}}$ and $\binom {n+r}{(n+r)/2}\approx 2^{n+r}  \sqrt{\frac{2}{ \pi(n+r}}$, this will happen roughly when $ (n+r) f(1/2)^2 \leq r$ or $r \geq \frac{n f(1/2)^2 }{ (1 - f(1/2)^2 }$.

So I think the answer depends a lot on how much smaller $f(1/2)$ is than $1$...

Comment: Yes, indeed.  The case I had in mind was $f(x) = (4x(1-x))^{n/2}/2$, such that $f(1/2) = 1/2$.  That was where I observed the limit of 1/3.  When I now do some experiments on different polynomials, a different limit is reached (e.g., for $f(x) = (4x(1-x))^{n/2}(3/4), f(1/2) = 3/4$, a limit of 5/4 appears to be reached).

Comment: But unfortunately, your last inequality is only a lower bound and not an upper bound. Let _m_ be its right hand side.  Then do we have $r \le floor(m)+1$?

Comment: @PeterO. I don't know, but the way I would check would be to use precise forms of Stirling's formula to estimate the factorials and thus the binomial coefficients.

Comment: Correction: In the example I gave earlier, the limit is actually 9/7, not 5/4.

Comment: @PeterO. This answer gives both a lower bound and an upper bound, they are just both approximate. One could possibly improve it to an exact bound using explicit bounds for binomial coefficients, but I don't want to do this.